# How to get the value of or Parse HTML dropdown selected:option text as variable in views.py in Django?

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have a 3 way dropdown list generated from 3 different tables linked via foreign keys.

[image: dropdown]
model.py is a follows

```
####################################################################################
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'State_Names'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name
####################################################################################
class District(models.Model):
    state_name = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    district_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000)])

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'District_Names'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.district_name
####################################################################################
class Block(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    district_name = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000)])
    block_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    block_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(8000)])
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Block_Names'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.block_name
```

The structure of `State` model/table is as: It has 36 unique values.
[image: State]

The structure of `District` model/table is as: It has 706 unique values for districts but has state as foreign key, so states are repeating as there are a no of districts in the state but the id is unique for district.
[image: District]

Similar way, The structure of `Block` model/table is as: which has around 7000 unique values for blocks but has district as foreign key, so both states and districts are repeating as there are a no of blocks in the district but the id is unique for block.
[image: Block]

views.py is as

```
def get_state_district_and_block_string(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        state_name_is=request.POST.get('state_dropdown')
        print("state_name_is", state_name_is)
        district_name_is=request.POST.get('district_dropdown')        
        block_name_is=request.POST.get('block_dropdown')

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Dropdown.html is as

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="state_dropdown">Select State</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="state_dropdown" name="state_dropdown" aria-label="...">
        <option selected disabled="true" class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown text-center"> --- Select State --- </option>
        {% for state in stateDetailsInDropdown %}
        <option class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown text-center" value="{{state.state_name}}">{{state.state_name}} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="district_dropdown">Select District</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="district_dropdown" name="district_dropdown" aria-label="...">
        <option selected disabled="true" class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown text-center"> --- Select District --- </option>
        {% for district in DistrictDetailsInDropdown %}
        <option class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown text-center" value="{{district.state_name}}">{{district.district_name}}  </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="block_dropdown">Select Block</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="block_dropdown" name="block_dropdown" aria-label="...">
        <option selected disabled="true" class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown text-center"> --- Select Block --- </option>
        {% for block in BlockDetailsInDropdown %}
        <option class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown text-center" value="{{block.state_name}}">{{ block.block_name}} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

From this Dropdown.html, the value which is being fetched by `views.py` out of this eg: `value="{{block.state_name}}">{{ block.block_name}}` is `1st set of curly brackets`

but I am interested in `2nd one containing the string of interest` because it returns same value of state by `request.POST.get` method in `1st set of curly brackets`

The Jquery is as follows for getting the related option (PS: dropdowns is only working fine for any 2 sets of variables, not for the last option )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var states = $('#state_dropdown');
        districts = $('#district_dropdown');
        
        districtOptions = districts.find('option');

        states.on('change',function(){
        districts.html(districtOptions.filter('[value="'+this.value+'"]'));
        }).trigger('change');

        let  = document.getElementById("district_dropdown").textContent;

        console.log("text", text)
      
      });
  

  $(document).ready(function(){
     var districts = $('#district_dropdown');

        blocks = $('#block_dropdown');
        
        blockOptions = blocks.find('option');

        districts.on('change',function(){
        blocks.html(blockOptions.filter('[value="'+this.value+'"]'));
        }).trigger('change');
      
      });
```

How to get the text of the selected option present in `2nd set of curly brackets` from the dropdown as a python variable in `views.py`.

Comment: Are all block.state_names different everytime or are there times where they will be the same?

Comment: They are different. But as as the value key is common in all the 3 models/table, it returns the value of state every time by request.POST.get method, instead of block or district value.

Comment: it they are always different, then you could add an id = '{{block.state_name}}' to each option in your loops-  which would be the same as the value of the option, so then you could get the value by var a = getElementbyId('state_dropdown').value(), now that you have the value of the option id, now you can do getElementById(a).innerHTML.     Probably not the most efficient way, but it should do the job

Comment: I looked every possibility, couldn’t not do it. kindly suggest

Comment: I have kept the state_id, district_id and block_id as unique in each table. So they are unique in that sense. They are interrelated with foreign key. The basic table structure is like: a state has many districts and a district has many blocks.

Comment: would an id = 'block_{{block.state_name}}', id = 'district_{{district.state_name}}' id = 'state_{{state.state_name}}' in your options make them unique enough?   then getElementById('block'+{{block.state_name}}.value())

Comment: @AdamJames, I have updated the question with ```model/table``` structure. How you get how the data is structured now.

Comment: but how would I call them via request.post.get("some_id")?

Comment: @AdamJames The jquery will not work this way, as I also had to keep the ```related districts``` in ```2nd dropdown``` after selecting the ```state``` from ```1st dropdown``` and so on. So districts will not appear in ```2nd dropdown```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245574/discussion-between-adam-james-and-abhilash-singh-chauhan).